# Gob Decoder Returning EOF Error

Tags: go, gob

I am attempting to implement an interface based message queue where jobs are pushed as bytes to a redis queue. But I keep receiving an EOF error when attempting to decode the byte stream.

https://play.golang.org/p/l9TBvcn9qg

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Comment: The enc.Encode(test) function returns an error, it's good practice to capture and check all possible errors

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I do usually catch and handle errors, but in this case I'm just trying to demonstrate a problem in encoding and decoding nested interfaces.

Comment: Sorry, I mean that call is returning an error, and when running the code and capturing the error, it shows "gob: type not registered for interface: main.B". Adding a gob.Register(B{}) before encoding prevents the EOF.

Comment: I TOTALLY forgot about having to register! Thank you Mark! I'll take note to  check for the error."

Comment: Questions and answers should include all the relevant code in them an not rely on a third party site (Go playground links are nice, but they should not be the only way to understand the question).

Answer (score 0):

In your Go Playground example, you're trying to encode an interface and interfaces don't have a concrete implementation. If you remove the interface from your `A` struct, that should work. Like the following:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "encoding/gob"
import "bytes"

type testInterface interface{}

type A struct {
  Name string
  Interface *B // note this change here
}

type B struct {
  Value string
}

func main() {
  var err error
  test := &A {
    Name: "wut",
    Interface: &B{Value: "BVALUE"},
  }
  buf := bytes.NewBuffer([]byte{})
  enc := gob.NewEncoder(buf)
  dec := gob.NewDecoder(buf)

  // added error checking as per Mark's comment
  err = enc.Encode(test)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
  }

  result := &A{}
  err := dec.Decode(result)
  fmt.Printf("%+v\n", result)
  fmt.Println("Error is:", err)
  fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
}
```

Also, just as a side note you will see some sort of output like the following: `&{Name:wut Interface:0x1040a5a0}` because `A` is referencing a reference to a `B` struct. To clean that up further:

```
type A struct{
  Name string
  Interface B // no longer a pointer
}

func main() {
   // ...
   test := &A{Name: "wut", Interface: B{Value: "BVALUE"}}
   // ...
}
```

Comment: I'm using interfaces to abstract the job queue so that I don't have to switch case assert to a specific struct type everytime. (There are many structs other than B implementing the testInterface)

Does this mean that I have no way to abstract a child field into an interface?

Comment: Great! Thats nice to know. I haven't personally used the `gob` package myself. I've used other `encoding` packages so I assumed it was the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to the problem from Mark above. I have forgotten to do a `gob.Register(B{})`

https://play.golang.org/p/7rQDHvMhD7

Answer (score 0):

I got this error by trying to load gob files which did not save() successfully, but I lacked sufficient error handling on save() to know it.

My save function is now a little insane, but I like it:

```golang
func SaveToDisk[T any](filepath string, data T) {
    f, err := os.Create(filepath)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(errors.Wrap(err, "os.Create()"))
    }
    defer func() {
        err := f.Close()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(errors.Wrap(err, "f.Close()"))
        }
    }()

    writer := bufio.NewWriter(f)
    dataEncoder := gob.NewEncoder(writer)
    err = dataEncoder.Encode(data)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(errors.Wrap(err, "dataEncoder.Encode()"))
    }
    err = writer.Flush() // Flush the data to the file
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(errors.Wrap(err, "writer.Flush()"))
    }
}
```

Turns out I was missing the error `dataEncoder.Encode(): gob: type not registered for interface: map[string]interface {}` during save().

`gob` cannot seem to marshal interfaces without any help, but you can register interface types with it to remedy that. To fix my problem, all I had to do was:

```golang
func init() {
    gob.Register(map[string]interface{}{})
}
```